# How to update the state in redux without using mapDispatchToProps() method

Tags: redux, reducers

I am trying to update the reducer state using :
store.dispatch(NameOftheReducer(data)).

It calls the Action creator but it does not update the reducer state. I dont want to create any React component from where i want to dispatch the state change. Is there any way to do so..Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your action creator? Maybe you're not returning the action?

Comment: Please post the contents of your action creator as well as how you handle the action in your reducer.

Comment: Could you please explain `NameOftheReducer(data)` it should be `NameOftheActionCreator(data)` instead

Answer (score 6):

Lets assume the `store` is stored stored somewhere global

then you can just

```
store.dispatch({
  type: "SOME_ACTION",
  value: "value"
})
```

if you have some actionCreator like:

```
function someAction(value) {
   return {
     type: "SOME_ACTION",
     value: value
   }
}
```

And and now you can use it with dispatch:

```
store.dispatch(someAction("some value"))
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: I was wondering which 'store' to export for the store.dipatch function. You can use the store that you have created with "store = configReduxStore();" function.

Might be using them with Provider Component around your Parent Components

Comment: @Akshay you are right, but that are redux basics

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood how component and redux state relates.

`redux` state change are done through actions regardless of which component is actually 'using' this state.

As long as you have an action creator defined somewhere, and you reducer handle the corresponding `action.type`, then you can use this action creator in whichever component.

There is no benefit of using `store` directly. `store` is stored in `context`, and it is generally considered bad practice using `context`. The nice thing about `redux` is that it takes care of this by giving you `Provider` and `connect`.

Except when initializing the app, you should always use `mapDispatchToProps` when you want to use action creators in your component.